# parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:]) not working

Tags: python, parsing

Hey guys so I have a problem that I've been trying to figure out. I have been using this code

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import sys
import argparse
 .....
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage=usage_msg)
print sys.argv[1:]
parser.add_argument("-1", action="store_true", dest="col1", default=False,
                  help="Suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)")
parser.add_argument("-2", action="store_true", dest="col2", default=False,
                  help="Suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)")
parser.add_argument("-3", action="store_true", dest="col3", default=False,
                  help="Suppress column 3")
parser.add_argument("-u", action="store_true", dest="unsorted", default=False,
                  help="Compare unsorted files")
options,args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

I then run the command:

```
./comm.py trace.tr testR
```

I thought the above method should work but I end up getting this error:

```
comm.py: error: unrecognized arguments: trace.tr testR
```

And was wondering why because I thought I set up everything correctly.

I need to parse two files that my program runs for.

Can anyone diagnose something I did wrong?

Comment: `ArugmentParser.parse_args` doesn't need you to pass in the command line arguments. Just call it with no arguments.

Comment: @ChristianDean I need to get the two files my program runs for though but I'm not sure what I did wrong. I even ran it with no arguments and still get an error.

Answer (score 3):

If you want `argparse` to require two positional arguments that are files to parse, *tell* it about them. Add something like:

```
parser.add_argument("tracefile", type=argparse.FileType("r"),
                  help="Trace file to parse")
parser.add_argument("testfile", type=argparse.FileType("r"),
                  help="Test file to parse")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

so it not only knows to expect the positional arguments, but ensures they are readable files and opens them for you. You can then access them after `parse_args` is called as `args.tracefile` and `args.testfile` (or whatever real name makes sense in your scenario).

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `parse_known_args` as opposed to `parse_args`:

```
options, args = parser.parse_known_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

After the call, `options` will be `Namespace(col1=False, col2=False, col3=False, unsorted=False)` and `args` will be `['trace.tr', 'testR']`

Comment: Thank you! Why does this work as opposed to just parse_args just curious.

Comment: @MichaelGee: `parse_known_args` parses what it recognizes, and ignores what it doesn't recognize. It's not a great solution, because it means unrecognized switches get silently ignored, rather than `argparse` detecting and reporting the misuse for you.

Comment: Well said, @ShadowRanger

Comment: What would you use if you want to write some test for code that parses the arguments? Should you mock the module? I hit a wall when trying to use parse_known_args in order to accommodate unittest flags and arguments.